# Proyecto angular ha dejado de funcionar al actualizarlo

Tags: angular

Hice un `upgrade` a mi proyecto y ahora no me deja ejecutarlo.

Este es el error que me manda:

```
H:\directorio>ng serve
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\miUsuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Me gustaria volver a la **version** que tenia, pero ni me habia fijado cual era, no hay una especie de **rollback** de versiones que directamente te devuelva a la version que tenias anterior a esta ?

Comment: Ve a la carpeta del proyecto desde la consola de Node y ejecuta npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: Me da error, `npm ERR! path C:\Users\miUsuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\miUsuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd: node_modules\angular-cli\bin\ng symlink target is not controlled by npm C:\Users\miUsuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\miUsuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\miUsuario\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-05T14_17_52_427Z-debug.log`